# Differences between "Developer I", "Developer III" and similar numbered role names

Tags: software-industry, title

Sometimes when browsing IT job ads I come across an ad looking for an "...administrator 1" or for a "...developer III".

Is there any kind of standard on the relative positioning between this kind of numbered roles? For example is a position numbered "1" higher than a similarly named position numbered "3", or is if the other way around?

**Update:** removed the links to the articles as this question was in any case not specific to them. As stated they were provided as examples of the naming convention.

As to the opinion that I should have read the job descriptions, the fact is that it had not answered the questions posted here (something that would have been evident to anyone actually reading this question before commenting).

Comment: If this is meant to be generic, don't include the links. You're just inviting people to answer the one example you gave. On the other hand, you probably should have read the descriptions that you posted more carefully.

Comment: Company-specific. Ask them.

Comment: *something that would have been evident to anyone actually reading this question before commenting* That line probably is not going to help the reception of your question.

Comment: The biggest difference between Developer I and Developer III is, undoubtedly, II.

Comment: Related: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38265/what-does-the-suffix-after-software-engineer-developer-job-titles-mean-e-g-s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no standard.  They put that there because it's the name of the position they're hiring for but the reality is without an actual description (specifically how much experience is required, responsibilities, etc.) it's a meaningless title beyond their own organization.

While not a standard, typically higher numbered titles are the more senior. A Developer I would usually be the lowest on the rung.

As I said, these aren't standards though so a company may do it differently, though I personally haven't seen any.

Answer (score 2):

These numbers should be thought of as skill levels, so level 1 is the lowest. You could have guessed that yourself; the [developer 1](https://www.smartrecruiters.com/AnalygenceInc/104901445-software-developer-i) requires four years experience, and the [developer 3](https://www.smartrecruiters.com/AnalygenceInc/104896199-software-developer-iii) requires eight years.

There's no standard though; what company X calls a developer 1, might be roughly the same as a developer 2 at company Y.

Note that this is different from e.g. a [first mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_mate) which is usually a high rank.